# Dual pane image browser and manager

Tags: osx, image-viewer

I'm looking for a dual pane (as in Total Commander) image browser / viewer / manager for Mac.

I would like to browse two different folders simultaneously and be able to preview the pictures in both panes right in the browser without actually opening them.

Being able to do quick edits (like in Graphic Converter) on the images would be a huge plus.

Paid or free app, either is OK.

[image: Example]

Comment: Why not arrange a pair of windows in [the Finder](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finder_(software))? Each navigates folders and displays an image for selected file. Be specific about what features you seek that are not provided by the Finder.

Comment: @BasilBourque the features I'm looking for are to be able to interact with both panes with keyboard shortcuts, for example, switching focus between the panes (folders) with 'Tab' key or moving and coping from one pane (folder) to another pane (folder) with a keyboard shortcut. Simultaneous browsing would also be a plus.

Comment: The best Total Commander replacement on macOS I know is [Marta](https://marta.sh/). It does not support previewing images integrated to my knowledge though.

Comment: @MichaelS. looks pretty good. Since it supports Lua I guess it could be extended to do a lot of stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in the terminal (iTerm) by splitting your pane and then installing shell integration. When you install shell integration, it gives you an option to include some image utilities. If you include these, the command: `imgcat filename.png` will display an image inline. In a split terminal window, or 2 terminal windows both displayed, you can view a different image in each window. And while in terminal mode, you can do as you please with the image files. You can even split a terminal window horizontally and vertically generating 4 windows to view 4 images at once.

Comment: That's pretty slick! But I assume I can only view the files this way, no editing like resizing, rotating, etc?

Comment: well you probably have imageMagic, another command line tool, which supposedly does a bunch of cool stuff.  I've never used it because I haven't edited images much.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out my OSX file manager of choice, [Path Finder](https://cocoatech.com/#/) works as an excellent dual-pane image viewer!

[image: Path Finder in dual-pane mode]

Although it is still a file manager not an image browser/manager, so I can't do quick edits as in Graphic Converter for example. So, if there are other solutions, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Graphic Converter 10 can be used in this fashion. Once you open the app, go to "File" -> "Duplicate Browser". This will create another instance of the same browser window. If you arrange them side by side you can use a shortcut to toggle between windows. You can drag and drop images between the windows too. But I think that this is pretty much it as far as interaction between windows is concerned.

[image]